# How do I pass a method with two arguments to a Minitest Spec assertion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

With Minitest Spec in Rails I'm trying to check if an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` is in a certain range. I thought to use the `between?` method that takes the min and max of the range. Here's how I'm expressing that in Minitest Spec:

```
_(language_edit.curation_date).must_be :between?, 10.seconds.ago, Time.zone.now
```

but it gives me this error:

> Minitest::UnexpectedError: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1
>   for 2)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `between?` expects two arguments. You have a comma after it, I suggest you use parentheses. `between?(10.seconds.ago, Time.zone.now)`

Comment: @radubogdan I'm not using the `between?` method directly here,  I'm passing it to the `must_be` method - see how it's a symbol in this context.

Comment: You're right but you're still passing only 1 argument to between?

Comment: Sorry but what if you use normal assert? `assert language_edit.curation_date.between?(10.seconds.ago, Time.zone.now)` ... between? already returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `must_be` is implemented as `infect_an_assertion :assert_operator, :must_be`

**assert_operator**

```
# File lib/minitest/unit.rb, line 299
def assert_operator o1, op, o2, msg = nil
  msg = message(msg) { "Expected #{mu_pp(o1)} to be #{op} #{mu_pp(o2)}" }
  assert o1.__send__(op, o2), msg
end
```

What if you use assert directly?

Example:

```
class DateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "using assert with between? should work" do
    a = 5.seconds.ago

    assert a.between?(10.seconds.ago, Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, I could just use assert directly, but it defeats the purpose of having Minitest Spec. It looks like `must_be` is designed to be used with an operator method, not any generic method, so it only lets you have things with one argument.

Comment: That's right :) I read the source code and I don't think it can work with methods with multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to radubogdan for showing me some of the code behind the `must_be` method. It looks like it's designed to be used with operators like this:

```
_(language_edit.curation_date).must_be :>, 10.seconds.ago
```

and a side-effect of this is it works with boolean methods that take one or no arguments, but not with methods that take more than one argument. I think I'm supposed to do this:

```
_(language_edit.curation_date.between?(10.seconds.ago, Time.zone.now)).must_equal true
```